# Os Check And prompt proper if

Tags: python, operating-system

Can python see which windows i use e.x. windows 7 windows xp windows vista and if windows vista print you use windows vista, or execute other command

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Look at [`platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html).

Comment: platform lives in sys module.  import sys  sys.platform

Comment: @Aaron: `sys` has a `platform` attribute, but there is also a separate `platform` module.

Comment: @Ignacio: oh nice, didn't know that

Comment: nice but what when we want to chose between versions of windows??

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the various functions in the module yet?

Comment: i have tryed to search platform.system_alias but how do i know what the alias of every system are??

Answer (score 2):

```
import platform
platform.system()  # => 'Windows'
platform.release() # => 'Vista'
platform.version() # => '6.1.7600'
```

I believe if platform.version() returns a value of 6.1.7000 or higher, you're on a Windows 7 machine, otherwise it is Vista.